# Vaadin - Is there a possibility of using overlays for my own forms?

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin14

I have an idea to making a form (in Vaadin 14 LTS)which would overlaid main layout for better user experience (like `LoginOverlay`). The thing is, `vaadin-overlay` is meant only for internal use and I presume I can't use that for my own form... Is there other way to make overlays?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What about using a full screen dialog? What's your use case?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli

I want to add entry to calendar; I can easily make a typical form to adding a entry, the thing is I wish to that look cooler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Dialog to make an overlay. See https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/dialog for code examples.